# How to generate templated Airflow DAGs using Jinja

Tags: python, airflow, jinja2, templating, mwaa

I'm bit new to Airflow and was exploring creation of multiple DAGs that have more or less same code from a template instead of creating them as individual DAGs which introduces maintenance overhead. I found [this article on medium](https://medium.com/@alimasri1991/auto-generating-airflow-dags-3c8c4aa6ad11) and it works well for simpler use cases. But when final DAG itself needs to have templated fields like dag_run.conf or var.val.get etc, it fails as JINJA is trying to render them as well. I tried to include such templated fields in my template it throws following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user7\Git\airflow-test\airflow_new_dag_generator.py", line 17, in <module>
    output = template.render(
  File "C:\Users\user7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 1090, in render
    self.environment.handle_exception()
  File "C:\Users\user7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 832, in handle_exception
    reraise(*rewrite_traceback_stack(source=source))
  File "C:\Users\user7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\jinja2\_compat.py", line 28, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\user7\Git\airflow-test\templates\airflow_new_dag_template.py", line 41, in top-level template code
    bash_command="echo {{ dag_run.conf.get('some_number')}}"
  File "C:\Users\user7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 471, in getattr
    return getattr(obj, attribute)
jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'dag_run' is undefined
```

**airflow_test_dag_template.py**

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import os

DAG_ID: str = os.path.basename(__file__).replace(".py", "")
CITY = "{{city}}"
STATE = "{{state}}"

DEFAULT_ARGS = {
    'owner': 'airflow_test',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
}

with DAG(
        dag_id=DAG_ID,
        default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
        dagrun_timeout=timedelta(hours=12),
        start_date=datetime(2023, 1, 1),
        catchup=False,
        schedule_interval=None,
        tags=['test']
) as dag:
    # Defining operators

    t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id="t1",
        bash_command=f"echo INFO ==> City : {CITY}, State: {STATE}"
    )

    t2 = BashOperator(
        task_id="t2",
        bash_command="echo {{ dag_run.conf.get('some_number')}}"
    )

    # Execution flow for operators
    t1 >> t2
```

**airflow_test_dag_generator.py**

```
from pathlib import Path
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

file_loader = FileSystemLoader(Path(__file__).parent)
env = Environment(loader=file_loader)
dags_folder = 'C:/Users/user7/Git/airflow-test/dags'

template = env.get_template('templates/airflow_test_dag_template.py')

city_list = ['brooklyn', 'queens']

state = 'NY'

for city in city_list:
    print(f"Generating dag for {city}...")
    file_name = f"airflow_test_dag_{city}.py"
    output = template.render(
        city=city,
        state=state
    )

    with open(dags_folder + '/' + file_name, "w") as f:
        f.write(output)
    print(f"DAG file saved under {file_name}")
```

I tried to run **airflow_test_dag_generator.py** with keeping only operator t1 in my template(**airflow_test_dag_template.py**) it works well and generates multiple DAGs as expected. But if I include t2 in the template which contains a templated field like dag_run.conf, then JINJA throws above mentioned error while reading the template.

Can someone please suggest how to not render keywords like dag._run.conf, var.val.get and task_instance.xcom_pull etc. or an alternate solution to this use case.

Answer (score 2):

Your template is trying to reference a variable named `dag_run`, but you haven't provided any such variable to the `template.render` statement, so of course you're getting the `UndefinedError`.

If you want the text `{{ dag_run.conf.get('some_number')}}` to appear literally in the rendered template, you'll need to escape the `{{...}}` markers so that they aren't interpreted by Jinja when processing the `airflow_test_dag_template.py` template.

You can do that using the `{% raw %}` directive:

```
bash_command="echo {% raw %}{{ dag_run.conf.get('some_number')}}{% endraw %}"
```

Or by putting the text inside of a Jinja string expression:

```
bash_command="echo {{ "{{ dag_run.conf.get('some_number')}}" }}"
```